# Highlighting the correct cell when data validating

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing data validation using the following code and I am unsure why the cell shown in the picture is being highlighted. I would like the cell selected to be highlighted instead. I suspect its something to do with the xlup. For reference the cell being highlighted is currently in row 3 where as I would like it to be in row 6.

Here is my code:

```
Sub country()

Dim cell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Sheets("Temp").Select
lastRow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range("N6:" & "N" & lastRow)
If Len(cell.Value) <> 3 And Len(cell.Value) <> 0 Then
    cell.Offset(0, -10).Value = cell.Offset(0, -10).Value & "Invalid entry in column, "
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `lastRow` will be whatever row has that "3" in it - did you need it to be some other value?  In any case N6 has no content and so would not satisfy your `Len(cell.Value) <> 0` condition

Comment: Hi, I don’t want the validations to go above the 6th row. So ideally there I would have the highlight where the selection is.

Answer (score 0):

JHill,

I don't know why your cell is highlighted as in my testing what ever cell was highlighted when the macro is started remains highlighted.

However, I would suggest your change your code as follows as Len() return 0 for a numeric value, which would be an error in your code that is not caught.

```
Sub Test()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell    As Range

lastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Debug.Print "Last Row: " & lastRow

For Each cell In Range("N1:" & "N" & lastRow)

   If Len(cell) = "" Or Len(cell) = 3 Then
'***         If Len(cell.Value) <> 3 And Len(cell.Value) <> 0 Then
     cell.Offset(0, -10).ClearContents
     cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
   Else
     cell.Offset(0, -10).Value = cell.Value & " Invalid entry in column, "
     cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
   End If
   
Next cell

End Sub
```

Test:

[image]

HTH